# Hide a specific y axis label in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot in R and I would like to hide a specific label without manipulating the data used to produce the plot. Is this possible? I would like to hide the y label denoted as 5000. I tried using the element blank in my code but it did not work as desired.

My code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds) 

diamonds %>% 
   ggplot(aes(table)) +
   geom_histogram() +
   labs(
    x = "scores",
    y = "Frequency") +
    (themes = list(theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())))
```

Comment: Probably! Please include some example data and code so we can understand your use case better and make more relevant suggestions.

Comment: You need to be more specific about *what* you want to hide. Cal shows you below how to hide a y-axis label. Something similar can be achieved for the x-axis. In your comment you ask how about to hide a legend label (only the text? or the symbol as well?). This is not clear. "hide a specific label" can refer to almost anything in a (gg)plot. Please be specific.

Comment: @MauritsEvers , I would like to hide a specific x-axis label on my plot without manipulating the data. For example; In a bar chart, if the x labels of the bars are, "x", "y", and "z", I would like to hide the bar "z" for example. I know I can filter based on the data but is there a way I can hide the bar or the x-label once have plotted the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're going for, but scale_y_continuous gives you some control.

```
diamonds %>% 
       ggplot(aes(table)) +
       geom_histogram() +
       labs(
             x = "scores",
             y = "Frequency") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c(10000, 15000), breaks=c(10000, 15000))
```

Comment: what about in a case where the axis label is not continuous but just a text label. For example ;                                                                                                            
`library(ggplot2)`
`ggplot(diamonds) `

`df<-diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  count() `
 `ggplot(df, aes(x=cut, y=n, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+theme_minimal()`
 
 I would like to hide the "Fair" bar without manipulating the data

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment "I would like to hide a specific x-axis label on my plot without manipulating the data", here is an example.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("setosa", "", "virginica"))
```

[image]

This will hide the x-axis label for the second entry. Mind you, the order of labels is (by default) given by lexicographical ordering. So you will need to know the ordering first, before you can hide a specific label.